# Shellscript: Is it possible to format seq to display n numbers per line?

Tags: linux, shell, loops, formatting, seq

Is it possible to format seq in a way that it will display the range desired but with N numbers per line?

Let say that I want seq 20 but with the following output:

```
1 2 3 4 5        
6 7 8 9 10        
11 12 13 14 15        
16 17 18 19 20
```

My next guess would be a nested loop but I'm not sure how... 
Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: `seq 20 | xargs -n 5` should do the deed you need. Or if you are using bash `echo {1..20} | xargs -n 5` will do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use can use `awk` to format it as per your needs.

```
$ seq 20 | awk '{ORS=NR%5?FS:RS}1'
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20
```

`ORS` is `awk`'s built-in variable which stands for Output Record Separator and has a default value of `\n`. `NR` is `awk`'s built-in variable which holds the line number. `FS` is built-in variable that stands for Field Separator and has the default value of space. `RS` is built-in variable that stands for Record Separator and has the default value of `\n`.

Our action which is a ternary operator, to check if `NR%5` is true. When it `NR%5` is not 0 (hence true) it uses `FS` as Output Record Separator. When it is false we use `RS` which is newline as Output Record Separator.

`1` at the end triggers `awk` default action that is to print the line.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `xargs` to limit the sequence displayed per line.

```
$ seq 20 | xargs -n 5
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20
```

The parameter `-n 5` tells xargs to only display 5 sequence numbers.

If you have bash you can use the builtin sequence.

```
echo {1..20} | xargs -n 5
```

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement to post it.

Comment: +1 For simplicity.  Note that for very large number sets this would be slow.

Answer (score 1):

Using Bash:

```
while read num; do 
    ((num % 5)) && printf "$line " || echo "$line"
done < <(seq 20)
```

Or:

```
for i in {1..20}; do
    s+="$i "
    if ! ((i % 5)); then
        echo $s
        s=""
    fi
done
```

Comment: Since you are in control of the value of `i` then eval won't hurt. You can say `for i in {1..20..5}; do eval echo {$i..$(($i+4))}; done`. The only caveat, increment is supported only on bash version 4.X.

Comment: Yes, another good solution.  Would be faster for large number sets.